# How to generate similar sentence by given sentence?

Tags: computational-linguistics

I'd like to generate a similar sentence by a given sentence.

e.g.

by given

> "Mike, this is an apple."

can generate

> "Tom, this is a pear."

Which software can I use for such generation?

**Only English is OK for me and any hardware/program platform is OK for me.**

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics! This question is way too broad. You should at least limit the language, the hardware, and programming environment (because you will probably need some coding by yourself). Also, it may be helpful if you told us **what have you tried so far**.

Comment: You may search for Natural Language Generation topics or Paraphrasing tools on Github.

Answer (score 1):

Any software based on CFG (Context Free phrase structure Grammar) would easily describe the relationship among constructions produced by substitution within a grammatical category, since this is basic to the CFG theory. For instance, the Unix Yacc program parses CF languages (mostly).

However, to use such a general purpose program, you would have a lot of work to do to describe a large enough part of English to the program to get any interesting results.
Perhaps someone else can suggest a tool that is already set up to deal with English.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleNLG](https://github.com/simplenlg/simplenlg):

```
Lexicon lexicon = Lexicon.getDefaultLexicon();
NLGFactory phraseFactory = new NLGFactory(lexicon);
Realiser realiser = new Realiser(lexicon);

List<String> addressees = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Mike", "Tom" });
List<String> objectHeads = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "apple", "pear" });

addressees.forEach(a -> {
    objectHeads.forEach(h -> {
        NPPhraseSpec o = phraseFactory.createNounPhrase("a", h);
        SPhraseSpec c = phraseFactory.createClause("this", "be", o);
        c.addFrontModifier(a);
        c.addFrontModifier(", ");
        DocumentElement s = phraseFactory.createSentence(c);
        System.out.println(realiser.realise(s).getRealisation());
    });
});
```

Which results in:

> Mike, this is an apple.
>
> Mike, this is a pear.
>
> Tom, this is an apple.
>
> Tom, this is a pear.